# Moving a row to another worksheet based on a cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I'm trying to write something that would COPY an entire row if a cell has a "Yes" in it.

the source is on a worksheet called "Master List" the target worksheet is called "CE Class"

If Column F has a "yes" then copy the row from "Master List" and put it on "CE Class" starting on row 4.

Comment: .... When you say `VGA` (Video Grapics Array) do you actually mean `VBA` (Visual Basic for Applications)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the typo

Comment: lets say you are in sheet 2 and if you want to refer from sheet 1 use =sheet1!A1    Use ! to refer to other sheet

Comment: i hope it answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you based on your provided description.  I commented the code to try to make it clear what it's doing and why.

```
Sub tgr()

    'Declare variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim FCell As Range

    'Assign object variables
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Master List")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("CE Class")

    'Loop through each cell in column F
    For Each FCell In wsData.Range("F1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Cells
        'Check if the F Cell's value is "yes"
        If Trim(LCase(FCell.Value)) = "yes" Then
            'Found a "yes", add it to rCopy
            If rCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rCopy = FCell
            Else
                Set rCopy = Union(rCopy, FCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next FCell

    'Check if there is any data to copy over
    If Not rCopy Is Nothing Then
        'There is data to copy, clear the old results
        wsDest.Range("A4", wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A")).EntireRow.Clear

        'Copy over the data
        rCopy.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A4")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use VBA, just go to the desired cell and paste the logic command.

=IF(f1="yes",masterlist!A1)
FYI: the command also works in vba 

 you can also play around with the A1 value and see how it works